# Excel VBA - How to fix scroll bar value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 scroll bars in a user form:

[Scroll bars - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Kqm.png)

As you can see, the little square is always positioned at 0. **I need these squares to start at pre-defined values (position)**. Below is the code I'm using at the moment, but it's not working.

[Example of what the scroll bar should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L3Br.png)

```
Private Sub rng_cbb_IndProd_Change() 'everything changes when I select something (basically).
   
frmSeg.rng_seg_4.Value = 10
frmSeg.rng_seg_3.Value = 20
frmSeg.rng_seg_2.Value = 30

End Sub
```

*Please note the code is simplified, the necessary variables are all set.*

Comment: Put the initialization code in the _form_ initialize event

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more? I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and it was simpler than I thought.

Nothing was happening even though I was inputting a value, and that's because I didn't set a MIN/MAX value to the scroll bars.

```
 frmSeg.rng_seg_4.Min = 0
 frmSeg.rng_seg_4.Max = 100

 frmSeg.rng_seg_4.Value = 10
```

By setting the min and max value, it can know position the scroll bar.